# Incorrect syntax error near ')' in the below code

Tags: asp.net

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Hospdb(@PatientId,@PatientName,@Password,@Emailid,@ContactNumber,@Address)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PatientId", txtPatID.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PatientName", txtPatName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emailid", txtEmailId.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactNumber",txtContactNumber.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtAddress.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Is your sql correct? Shoudnt be there a _values_ clause?

Comment: syntax error... where?  In the actual code posted?  As in a compiler error?  Or sql server is complaining about a syntax error?  Have you tried profiling and looking at what is wrong with the statement hitting your database?

Answer (score 0):

Your Insert statement is wrong! Check the following MSDN Links for  more info:

[MSDN Insert Statement Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx)

[MSDN Insert statement with SQLCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h54fa37c(v=vs.80).aspx)

You need to write it as following:

```
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into [Hospdb] ([PatientId], [PatientName],[Password],[Emailid],[ContactNumber],[Address]) 
    Values (@PatientId,@PatientName,@Password,@Emailid,@ContactNumber,@Address)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PatientId", txtPatID.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PatientName", txtPatName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emailid", txtEmailId.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactNumber",txtContactNumber.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtAddress.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```